# buttons in sliding drawer are not responding

Tags: java, android, xml, button, slidingdrawer

I am creating an project of android application by linking MySQL database using PHP. I am facing a problem that the click event on a button in sliding drawer is not working.

layout of sliding drawer

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sliding"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
<Button
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/handle"

    android:background="@drawable/up"
    />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/proftv"
            android:background="@drawable/menubuttonshape"
            android:text="My Profile"
            android:textColor="#e692818a"

            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/foodmenutv"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:text="Foodmenu"
            android:background="@drawable/menubuttonshape"
            android:textColor="#e692818a"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menubuttonshape"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/packagetv"
            android:text="Packages"
            android:textColor="#e692818a"
            android:onClick="pkbt"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menubuttonshape"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/balancetv"
            android:text="My Balance"
            android:textColor="#e692818a"
            android:onClick="balbt"/>
        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/menubuttonshape"

            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reviewtv"
            android:text="My Review"
            android:textColor="#e692818a"
            android:onClick="revbt"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menubuttonshape"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/logouttv"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:textColor="#e692818a"
            android:onClick="logbt"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </SlidingDrawer>
```

Java code:

```
fmenu=(Button) findViewById(R.id.foodmenutv);
    handle=(Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);
    sliding=(SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.sliding);
    sliding.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened() {
            handle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down);
            //sliding.unlock();
        }
    });
    sliding.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed() {
         handle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up);
        }
    });

    fmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"hell",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foodmenu);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try after removing the clickable="true" property in your  Layout.May be that causes the problem

`

> `

Comment: @peter thnx ur cmnt solved my expandable list touch problem bt still m having a problem with sliding drawer content click response. as per ur suggestion i removed all clickable ="true". and if i add this then nothing is response.

Comment: @peter thanks for your comment. you solved my sliding drawer problem but now due to changes happen my expandable list view is not working. if i remove clickable="true" from sliding drawer too then expandable list view is working. tell me what to do..